# Iterating through current month to get all events

Tags: java, android, events, listview

I have a calendar app. I want to add a listview which displays all the events for the current month.

This is the code which I am using to loop but it displays only the last event of the month, instead of *ALL* the events:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < _calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); i++){
        if(isHoliday(i, month, year, date_value))
        {


            String date= i + " " + getMonthForInt(month);
            CalendarEvents events = new CalendarEvents();
            final ArrayList<Event> e = new ArrayList<Event>();
            e.addAll(events.eventDetails(hijri_date[1], hijri_date[0]));

            for (int j = 0; j < e.size(); j++)
            {
               Event event = e.get(j);
               summary_data = new Summary[]
                {
                   new Summary(date, event.eventdetails)
                };
            } 
        }
    }


summaryAdapter = new SummaryAdapter(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview_item_row, summary_data);

calendarSummary = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.calendarSummary);
calendarSummary.setAdapter(summaryAdapter);
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
CalendarEvents events = new CalendarEvents();
final ArrayList<Event> e = new ArrayList<Event>();
String date;

for(int i = 0; i < _calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); i++){
    if(isHoliday(i, month, year, date_value))
    {
        date = i + "-" + month + "-" + year;

        e.addAll(events.eventDetails(month, day));
        summary_data = new Summary[e.size()];

        for (int j = 0; j < e.size(); j++)
        {

           Event event = e.get(j);
           summary_data[j] = new Summary(date, event.eventdetails);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: The doc says that the first day of month is 1: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_MONTH ... But in your case it seems the first day would be 0. And you'll be skipping the last day of the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating array every time and assigning to same reference. That is why last one replacing everything else.

```
 summary_data = new Summary[]
                {
                   new Summary(date, event.eventdetails)
                };
```

You know the size ahead, so create array with size first and then assign values to index

```
summary_data = new Summary[e.size()];



 for(....)
    {
 ......
    summary_data[j] = new Summary(date, event.eventdetails);
    }
```

/////

```
if(isHoliday(i, month, year, date_value))
    {
       String date = i + "-" + month + "-" + year;
```

Comment: What should I do that it doesn't replace?

Comment: You need to create array ahead and assign values to index. See my example. Otherwise you can use list and add also.

Comment: I created the array ahead yet same result. Only the last event is displayed: `summary_data = new Summary[e.size()];
  for (int j = 0; j < e.size(); j++)
  {
     Event event = e.get(j);
     /*summary_data = new Summary[]
   {
      new Summary(date, event.eventdetails)
   };*/
     summary_data[j] = new Summary(date, event.eventdetails);
  }`

Comment: Print  e.size(); and see what is the size.

Comment: `e.size()` = 1. But I have 3 events in the current month.

Comment: You need to figure out why size is 1. Then only we can proceed.

Comment: Thanks. I finally got it working by initializing `CalendarEvents` before the loop. One last thing, the first two event dates gets replaced by the last event date value. How do I put it in an array so that it doesn't get replaced?

Comment: I don't think that is issue with looping. Can you update the code again. You might be using wrong index.

Comment: Remove String date declaration outside loop and define it inside as shown in my answer.